# Como realizar uma ação antes do 'mousedown' em javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Minha intenção no final das contas é transformar um 'mousedown' em um "ctrl + mousedown". Mas so consigo ativar o 'ctrl' depois do 'mousedown' ser processado.

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CC option').on('mousedown', function(event){ 
        event.ctrlKey = true;
    }); 
});
```

Dessa for ele ativa o ctrlKey depois do mousedown. Mas quero que ative antes. Como fazer isso? Estou conhecendo agora esses metodos do JS(preventDefault, addEventListener) e não sei como trabalhar direito com eles, mas acredito que com algum deles posso cosneguir o que quero.

Comment: O que você realmente pretende fazer? Não acho que seja possível simular a tecla `ctrl` dessa forma.

Comment: Minha intenção final é utilizar isso num select multiple para selecionar varios no click(mousedown) do mouse. Mas o IE não identifica eventos nas options. Como você pode ver no meu fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fp4WD/5/

Comment: se vc não usar o jquery e colocar o 3 parametro do `addEventlistener` como `true` (useCapture) ele vai ser executado antes do evento que você deseja chegar, porém isso só vai funcionar nos browsers modernos com suporte a `useCapture`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Actualização

Após ler o teu comentário e reler a tua pergunta as coisas já fazem outro sentido.

Assumindo que pretendes permitir a selecção de múltiplas opções sem que o utilizador faça uso da tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, poderás atingir esse fim da seguinte forma:

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7eHNn/)

```
var multiSelect = {};
function init() {      
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].multiple) {
      var n = s[i].name;
      multiSelect[n] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < s[i].options.length; j++) {
        multiSelect[n][j] = s[i].options[j].selected;
      }
      s[i].onclick = changeMultiSelect;
    }
  }
}
function changeMultiSelect() {
  var n = this.name;
  for (var i=0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
    if (this.options[i].selected) {
      multiSelect[n][i] = !multiSelect[n][i];
    }
    this.options[i].selected = multiSelect[n][i];
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

<sup>Ver [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14356963/352449) do @Vedmant no SOEN datada 16 Jan 2013.</sup>

---

## Resposta Original

<sup>A resposta original foi dada sobre o entendimento de que era pretendido detectar que a tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd> estava em uso quando existia um `click` com o rato.</sup>

Não existe nenhuma forma de simular o uso de determinada tecla sem que o utilizador realmente a utilize.

Este teu exemplo:

```
event.ctrlKey = true;
```

Não faz rigorosamente nada, não tem um impacto real na tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd> nem no evento associado ao uso da mesma.

Mesmo que surtisse algum efeito, não ia ser fácil tornar isso numa solução viável, pois em MAC por exemplo, utiliza-se a tecla <kbd>cmd</kbd>.

<sup>Ver [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396378/352449) do @Juhana no SOEN datada 22 Fev 2012.</sup>

### Solução

Largando a tua abordagem inicial pela inviabilidade da mesma, podes sim estar atento ao uso dessa tecla em junção com o click do rato.

Para isso aplicas o evento de `click` ao teu elemento e verificas se tens a tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd> clicada também:

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/g7A5n/)

```
$(selector).click(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    //Ctrl+Click fazer algo
  }
});
```

<sup>Ver [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485351/352449) do @Nick Craver♦ no SOEN datada 21 Mar 2010.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu sei, alterar os valores passados na variável que identifica o evento não possui nenhum efeito real, portanto não faz sentido alterar esses valores esperando que o navegador tenha uma reação diferente da esperada.

**EDIT**

Uma vez identificada sua intenção de selecionar múltiplos elementos do `select multiple` sem a tecla <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, achei a seguinte solução:

[Multi select avoiding ctrl button, provided by pure select tag and jQuery](http://nerdstuckathome.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/multi-select-avoiding-ctrl-button/)

A solução pode ser achada no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lzzluca/X8V2w/light/)... e como o jsfiddle não funciona nas versões mais antigas do IE, aqui está a versão [embedded do jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lzzluca/X8V2w/embedded/result/), a qual testei no IE 8 e funcionou.